# K-medoids in python (Pyclustering)

Tags: python-3.x

list nodes under same cluster (using pyclustering-k_medoid) - Order them closest to farthest

I use the .get_clusters() function under k-medoids/yclustering to get all clusters. I can print out all clusters and medics. I would like to print them ordered (closet to farthest)

what I need to do is to list all nodes belonging to a cluster (again I use pyclustering with some random initial seeds to do k-medoids).  I'd like to print out all nodes in a cluster ordered by their distance to the corresponding medoid for that cluster. Let say node "14" is the medoid of a cluster. I'd like to know how to print out node 3, 10, 23, 2 (based on how close they are to the center). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort nodes in line with their distances to their clusters, here is an example:

```
from pyclustering.samples.definitions import SIMPLE_SAMPLES
from pyclustering.cluster.kmedoids import kmedoids
from pyclustering.utils import read_sample
import pyclustering.utils.metric as metric

sample = read_sample(SIMPLE_SAMPLES.SAMPLE_SIMPLE3)

kmedoids_instance = kmedoids(sample, [8, 23, 36, 50])
kmedoids_instance.process()

clusters = kmedoids_instance.get_clusters()
medoids = kmedoids_instance.get_medoids()

for i in range(len(clusters)):
    medoid_point = sample[medoids[i]]

    clusters[i] = sorted(clusters[i], key=lambda index: metric.euclidean_distance(medoid_point, sample[index]))
    print(clusters[i])
    print("\n")
```